# Postgres - Multiple conditions on single column with the WHERE AND condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have a query as follows:

```
SELECT AVG(ratings.rating)
FROM ratings
INNER JOIN movies 
ON movies.movieid = ratings.movieid
INNER JOIN hasagenre
ON hasagenre.movieid = movies.movieid
INNER JOIN genres
ON hasagenre.genreid = genres.genreid
WHERE genres.name = 'Comedy'
```

The last line is most important for this, it gets the average rating of all `COMEDY` movies.

But overall, I have a couple of tables related to a movie database like `movies(title,id)`,`genres(name,id)`,`ratings(movie,rating)`,`hasagenre(movie,genre)`.....Ex:

```
Movie     | Genre
------------------
Get Smart | Comedy 
Get Smart | Romance 
Scream    | Horror
```

I then want to write a query that gets the average rating of movies that are both `COMEDY` and `ROMANCE`, i.e like `Get Smart`.Thus, I simply updated the last line of query as follows:

```
SELECT AVG(ratings.rating)
FROM ratings
INNER JOIN movies 
ON movies.movieid = ratings.movieid
INNER JOIN hasagenre
ON hasagenre.movieid = movies.movieid
INNER JOIN genres
ON hasagenre.genreid = genres.genreid
**WHERE (genres.name = 'Comedy' AND genres.name = 'Romance')**
```

However, that doesn't work and returns 0 rows even though I know for a fact that there are movies that satisfy both genres in the database. What is going wrong here?

What is the proper syntax for an multiple condition `AND` clause on the same column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you join all the tables to form an average you will multiply the number of rows due to the multiple genres involved. Instead figure out which movies meet the 2 genre condition first, then average the ratings of just those movies.

```
SELECT
    AVG(ratings.rating)
FROM ratings
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        hasagenre.movieid
    FROM hasagenre
    INNER JOIN genres ON hasagenre.genreid = genres.genreid
    WHERE genres.Name IN ('Comedy', 'Romance')
    GROUP BY
        hasagenre.movieid
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT genres.Name) = 2
) m ON ratings.movieid = m.movieid
```

Comment: Ohh this explains it! I didn't understand about multiplying the number of rows, thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

Use in  and aggregation condition

```
SELECT AVG(ratings.rating)
FROM ratings
INNER JOIN movies 
ON movies.movieid = ratings.movieid
INNER JOIN hasagenre
ON hasagenre.movieid = movies.movieid
INNER JOIN genres
ON hasagenre.genreid = genres.genreid 
  Where genres.Name in('Comedy', 'ROMANCE') 
group by hasagenre.genreid
having count(distinct genres.Name)=2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I thought `IN` is an `OR` condition, so it also would pick any movie that was either only `Comedy` (Tropic Thunder) or only `Romance` (Titantic). I need movies that are both? Or is my understanding wrong ?

Comment: That doesn't really work, does it? Group BY and Having are literally conflicting themselves. You can't have 2 distinct genres in a group by genre.

Answer (score 1):

You can also join genres twice:

```
SELECT AVG(ratings.rating)
FROM ratings
INNER JOIN movies 
ON movies.movieid = ratings.movieid
INNER JOIN hasagenre as hasagenre1
ON hasagenre1.movieid = movies.movieid
INNER JOIN hasagenre as hasagenre2
ON hasagenre2.movieid = movies.movieid
INNER JOIN genres as genresComedy
ON hasagenre1.genreid = genresComedy.genreid and genresComedy.name = 'Comedy'
INNER JOIN genres as genresRomance
ON hasagenre2.genreid = genresRomance.genreid and genresRomance.name = 'Romance'
```

But it may affect performance without right indexes.

Comment: The same record can't be both Comedy and Romance. You need to join twice with `hasgenre` for this to work.